# Extend Fullcalendar jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, bower

I need to sort all day events by priority. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=364#c53) I found solution. My problem is that I run bower to keep my packages up to date. Is there a way to implement the solution without messing with the plugin core file(s)?